# Error Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002) al conectar codeigniter con base de datos en servidor remota

Tags: php, mysqli, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Amigos estoy tratando de conectar mi aplicativo echo en codeigniter con una base de datos en un servidor remoto, al tratar de implementar la configuración de conexión me genera el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He tratado de implementar una conexión por separado, pensando que podría ser problemas del codeigniter pero no, sigue presentando el error, aquí el mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de conexion:

```
    <?php

    $servername = "192.168.0.104";
    $database = "adminrev_jv_revista";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "pass123";
    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";
    mysqli_close($conn);


    ?>
```

Y este es el de codeigniter:

```
    $active_group = 'default';
    $query_builder = TRUE;

    $db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'    => '',
        'hostname' => '192.168.0.104',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'pass123',
        'database' => 'mercado',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
    );
```

Tanto en mi servidor de pruebas local (Linux Ubuntu server 18.04) como en el de producción aparece este error, verán, cuento con dos servidores, uno apache y otro de uso exclusivo de base de datos, y de la misma forma lo replique exactamente igual, pero no se que puede estar pasando, alguien podría ayudarme a como solucionar este error.

Comment: ¿Estás conectando a un servidor remoto o tienes la base de datos en el mismo equipo? Si está en el mismo equipo intenta con `$servername = "localhost";`

Comment: servidor remoto, la arquitectura de despliegue cuenta con dos servidres, aplicativo y base de datos, en mi maquina, replique esa misma arquitectura para las pruebas del aplicativo antes del despliegue, pero en ambos ambientes me genera el mismo error, por lo que implementar el localhost en el servername no es viable

Comment: El servidor debe tener activa la opción para conexiones remotas, especificando el origen (IP) desde el que vas a conectar, y el puerto (generalmente 3306) debe estar abierto en ambos servidores.

Comment: No he pensado en eso, tal vez en mi caso e podido obviar este apartado al momento de implementar mis servidores, ¿sabes como puedo verificar y/o implementar eso en mis servidores? tal vez esa pueda ser la solucion

Comment: [Este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql#answer-48034562) (en inglés) te dice qué comandos ejecutar para habilitar la conexión remota desde la consola MySQL, faltaría abrir puertos en ambos servidores.

Comment: Amigo realize todo en el servidor de la base de datos, pero me genera el siguiente error Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión. incluso si estableci en el firewall el puerto 3306.

Comment: Crea otro usuario en el servidor de base de datos (sin especificar IP), con todos los permisos y trata de conectar con ese nuevo usuario.

Answer (score 0):

estaba con el mismo inconveniente, de hecho necesitaba conectarme a una base de datos local y otra remota al mismo tiempo y así comunicar dos aplicaciones.

Solo faltaba configurar correctamente el acceso remoto de MySQL --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/mysql-how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql#answer-48034562

Y luego al establecer la comunicación incluir el puerto de comunicación de MySQL en el servidor remoto, en mi caso  era 3307 (abrir el puerto en caso de Firewall)

```
$db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'    => '',
        'hostname' => '192.168.0.104:3307',
        'username' => 'root',
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hice esto y funcionó:

- Ingresar a la carpeta C:\xampp\mysql\data
- Eliminar todos los archivos, excepto my.ini y mysql_error.log. Obivamente no eliminar las carpetas.
- Reiniciar el servicio MySQL de XAMPP

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).